# char string works with cout, but destructor gives error

Tags: c++, string, memory, char

I have a complicated class which uses the following `char**`

```
char** Names=new char* [1000]
for (int j=0;j<1000;j++){Names[j]=new char [100];}
```

In the destructor, I make sure that `Names[j]` for `j=0` is pointing to some character string:

```
~Myclass()
{
cout<<"Name is: "<<Names[0]<<endl;
}
```

The output is: `Names is: Alex`

But `delete`ing the `Names[0]` in destructor gives error:

```
~Myclass()
{
cout<<"Name is: "<<Names[0]<<endl;
delete[] Names[0];
}
```

Here is a portion of erroneous output that I get:

```
7ff74ff1d000-7ff74ff85000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 202613632                  /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0
7ff74ff85000-7ff750184000 ---p 00068000 fd:00 202613632                  /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0
7ff750184000-7ff750188000 r--p 00067000 fd:00 202613632                  /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0
7ff750188000-7ff750189000 rw-p 0006b000 fd:00 202613632                  /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0
7ff750189000-7ff7501a9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 201328495                  /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
```

Comment: You are hopefully printing it and only *then* deleting it, right?

Comment: Please provide complete example. How are you deleting it in your destructor

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, first printing and then deleting.

Comment: @DKG please see the edited post. This is how I `delete`. My codes are complex, but in destructor I can clearly see the character string is printed properly. However, `delete` produces error.

Comment: when you delete this lines from destroctor is error persists?

Comment: Probably you already deleted it somewhere else. Also, why aren't you using an `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: *"I make sure that `Names[j]` for `j=0` is pointing to some character string"*. Does that by any chance mean `Names[j] = "Alex";`?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I am new to C++. After a while, I will begin using `std::vector`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I exactly meant that. Although `print` was working fine, but the source of issue was another thing explained in below answer.

Comment: Don't wait until using `std::vector`. Using resource managing objects is (1) easier to grasp for beginners (2) idiomatic (3) less error prone.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sounds very interesting. I will look into that soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a heap error. Based on the type of error message you are seeing, I suspect the pointer-to-char at Names[0] is pointing to a string "Alex" which lies in static memory.

Somewhere in your program, you might have done:

`Names[0] = "Alex";`

in which case the string "Alex" is in static memory. So when you call:

`delete [] Names[0];`

you are saying "delete something in static memory", which causes the runtime heap error you are seeing. The important point to realize is the operators `new` and `delete` only work on heap memory.

If instead you do something like:

`strcpy(Names[0], "Alex");`

you will not get the runtime heap error you are seeing.

Comment: great respond. The issue was exactly what you described. I had `Names[0]=A_String` in my code, where `A_String` is a variable of `std::string`. So `Names[0]` was pointing to somewhere in stack and that is why `delete` gave me error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create arrays with `new[]` then you need to use `delete[]`.

For your Names array destruction should be like this:

```
for (int j=0;j<1000;j++)
 delete[] Names[j];
delete[] Names;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this error. I fixed that in my post, but the main source of issue was another thing.